# Multiple Async series causing wrong behavior in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I'm using async library(the browser version) . I am stuck at the point where I see a fail in  the normal(read 'expected') behavior of [async series](https://github.com/caolan/async#seriestasks-callback) when i nest async calls inside one another.

Here are some fiddles producing wrong outputs

[fiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/saurshaz/en649/2/)

[fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/saurshaz/en649/6/)

The problem is summarized here

With the code as below

$(function () {

```
async.series([

function f1(cb) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("Hello from f1");
        cb(null);
    }, 3000);

    async.series([

    function f11(cb) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log("Hello from f11");
            cb(null);
        }, 3000);
    }, function f12(cb) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log("Hello from f12");
            cb(null);
        }, 3000);
    }, function f13(cb) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log("Hello from f13");
            cb(null);
        }, 3000);
    }], function (err, res) {
        console.log("Done all in f1");
    });

}, function f2(cb) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("Hello from f2");
        cb(null);
    }, 3000);
}],

function (err, res) {
    console.log("Done all");
});
```

});

I expected the output as below

```
Hello from f1 
Hello from f11
Hello from f12
Hello from f13
Done all in f1
Hello from f2 
Done all
```

But I am getting this -

```
Hello from f1
Hello from f11
Hello from f2
Done all 
Hello from f12
Hello from f13 
Done all in f1
```

Do you see the problem as I see? I think async.series gets confused because of multiple async series running at once. How can I pipe the nested ones into the main one , if that is the case. Anyone help @Caolan

The answer as per EDITs from @tom. It was a mistake to call cb(null) early in the code -- corrected code below

```
$(function () {

async.series([

function f1(cb) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("Hello from f1");
    }, 3000);

    async.series([

    function f11(cb1) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log("Hello from f11");
            cb1(null);
        }, 3000);
    }, function f12(cb1) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log("Hello from f12");
            cb1(null);
        }, 3000);
    }, function f13(cb1) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log("Hello from f13");
            cb1(null);
        }, 3000);
    }], function (err, res) {
        console.log("Done all in f1");
        cb(null);
    });

}, function f2(cb) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("Hello from f2");
        cb(null);
    }, 3000);
}],

function (err, res) {
    console.log("Done all");
});
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With asynchronous functions, invoking the callback is analogous to returning from a normal function in the sense that it resumes execution of the rest of the program. In function `f1`, invoking `cb` causes `f2` to be executed (which eventually prints `Hello from f2` and `Done all`).

To make sure `f2` is executed after `f11`, `f12` and `f13` have all finished, the call to `cb` should be moved to the final callback of the inner `async.series()` call, after the line `console.log("Done all in f1")`.

Comment: Yes that's correct. in order to simplify m question I made some edits. Which made the question loose it's meat.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please look at the fiddle also. i am editing the question t reflect what I meant.

Comment: Pls see the edited question. My question was on a different context. More clear now.

Answer (score 0):

The answer as per EDITs from @tom. It was a mistake to call cb(null) early in the code -- corrected code has been edited above in the question itself.